# can we compress a .csv file using ampscript or server side javascript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a .csv file that I would want to compress and use it in an email, I'm looking for an ampscript or serverside js to do it. is there one I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you can compress a file with a file transfer activity and upload to file location. AMPScript can then attach from the file location, if it's an FTP.